# Mac application doesn't respond for some time at start - how to debug?

Tags: macos, debugging

My Mac application doesn't respond for about 30 seconds on start before `applicationWillBecomeActive` is called. I have enough free memory and the CPU isn't (heavily) used. I stopped it in the debugger during the doesn't-respond-time, but can't find anything that helped me. The main thread is showing `semaphore_wait_trap` if this could help. I also tried some of the Instrument tools, but didn't see any obvious problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use Instruments (with the Time Profiler instrument), or the "Sample Process" button in Activity Monitor to get a profile of your app during the period and see what's keeping it busy. (Activity Monitor is probably the quickest and easiest tool to use in the first instance.)

Comment: I used the Sample Process in Activity Monitor and it helped me a lot. Looks like my persistent NSDocument has conflicts that can't be resolved. Thanks Paul!